# A fruit dealer fixes selling price of watermelon juice in such a way that he ends up earning a profit of 30% after paying tax which is 13%

Tags: arithmetic

A fruit dealer fixes selling price of watermelon juice in such a way that he ends up earning a profit of 30%  after paying tax which is 13% of the cost price. A shopkeeper buys watermelon juice from dealer and marks up the price by 15%  and then adds 25% water to juice. He then gives a discount of 4% on juice to his customers and thereby sells juice at Rs. 98.67 per litre . What is the cost price per litre of the watermelon juice for the fruit dealer ?

Let the C.P. of watermelon for fruit dealer be x.

Profit % = $\frac{profit}{100 \times C.P.}$
How can we tackle this question, no idea about this, please guide on this thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's call the original cost price $x$ as you've done, and perform all the indicated transformations.

The dealer sells his juice in such a  way as to make $30\%$ profit after paying tax of $13\%$ of cost of his returns. Thus, his selling price is $(100+30+13)\% x=1.43x.$

The shopkeeper increases the price by $15\%,$ so they now have $115\%×1.43x.$ They dilute the juice by $25\%,$ so it follows that per litre, they are actually selling $3/4$ of juice for $1.15×1.43x.$ Thus, for a complete litre of juice, the true selling price is $4/3×1.15×1.43x.$ After giving a discount of $4\%,$ the selling price is now $(100-4)\%×4/3×1.15×1.43x=0.96×4/3×1.15×1.43x,$ and this is equal to $\text{Rs}98.67.$ Thus, we must solve $$0.96×4/3×1.15×1.43x=98.67$$ for the original cost price $x.$

Comment: thats great.. thanks a lot...God bless you... thanks a lot once again. ..

Comment: @sultan Glad it helped.